# how Use ActionLink in Folder App_Code Mvc6 Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, app-code

I have created partial view in Folder App_Code and I just want to follow this method.
I don't want to use Action link in this Page .

If possible, can you share some sample code.

Grateful

Comment: You need to clean the question up. Partial views usually are placed in a Views folder so I suspect you mean something else.

Comment: I am obliged to define it partial view in Folder App_Code     .I'm just not recognizing the problem action Link in Folder App_Code